# Sum of row based on multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table displaying monthly budgets and am attempting to develop a formula that sums any month beyond a selection given in the formula.

In the link below, I have given an example, what criteria I have and the result I am hoping to achieve.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sfIpiu668VWTopiq_fjNe-8V_eNyrJIa5R20cS_4CPA/edit?usp=sharing

I appreciate any support and help that can be provided to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A5:A8,lambda(Σ,sum(ifna(filter(filter(Budget!B2:M,Budget!B1:M1>B2),Budget!A2:A5=Σ)))))
```

[image]